# Regression like transformation for vector maps

Tags: statistics, optimization, regression, linear-regression

Firstly, I am not a student of mathematics so although this question might be obvious to a lot of you, Its not obvious to me.

The idea is, given a function $f:\mathbb{R^1}\to \mathbb{R^1}$, were I to fit a linear equation $y=mx+c=f(x)$, to the data set $(x_1, y_1), (x_2,y_2), (x_3,y_3)....(x_n,y_n)$, I would want to minimize the error $e$ by tuning $m$ and $c$, where

$$e(m,c)=\sum_{i=1}^n\, (y_i - m x_i -c)^2$$

Now, if I had a function $f:\mathbb{R^2}\to \mathbb{R^2}$ such that I were to fit $\vec{Y}=[M]\vec{X}+\vec{C}$ to the data set, $(\vec{X_1},\vec{Y_1}),(\vec{X_2}, \vec{Y_2}), (\vec{X_3},\vec{Y_3}).......(\vec{X_n},\vec{Y_n})$, then does it boil down to the problem of minimizing $e([M],\vec{C})$ where

$$e([M],\vec{C})=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\,(\vec{Y_i}-[M]\vec{X_i}-\vec{C_i})\cdot(\vec{Y_i}-[M]\vec{X_i}-\vec{C_i})$$

Am I going in the right direction? Could you point me to some aleady available liteature for the same?
Note: $\vec{X}, \vec{Y}$ and $\vec{C}$ are column vectors of dimension $(2 ,1)$ while $[M]$ is a matrix of dimension $(2,2)$.

Comment: This will only work if you impose a norm or some other function that outputs an ordered value, e.g. $f: \mathbf{X}\to\mathbb{R}$. If I understand what your current intension correctly, then the image of your function will be in $\mathbb{R}^2$, which means you will not have an order between vectors and you will not be able to minimize the error

Comment: but the function that I want to minimize, $e([M],\vec{C})$ is in $\mathbb{R}$. Is that what you were asking? I basically want to find the values of $[M]$ and $\vec{C}$ for which $e([M], \vec{C})$ is minimized.

Comment: Let's be more specific. In linear regression (ignoring the intercept term $c$ for now), we solve $\min_{\mathbf{x}} \|\mathbf{y}-A\mathbf{x}\|^2$, where $\mathbf{y}\in\mathbb{R}^m$, represents $m$ samples' target and $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ is the features of $m$ samples, each sample with $n$ features. This is equivalent to $\min_{\mathbf{x}}\sum_{i=1}^m(y_i - \mathbf{a}_i^T\mathbf{x})^2$. Notice that in both cases we have $n$ features (independent variables). For the first example you gave $n=1$. Looks like in your second example you looked for $n>1$, which is possible as just explained

Comment: Lastly, the intercept term $c$ is incorporated into the data matrix $A$ and variable vector $\mathbf{x}$. We add an $m$-dimensional column $(1, 1, \dots, 1)^T$ to $A$ and another variable $x_i$ to the vector $\mathbf{x}$, getting an $m\times (n+1)$ data matrix and an $(n+1)$ coefficients vector. Again, in the first 1-D feature vector you gave, this is equivalent to adding $c$.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I understand